# PHP comparison of two values?

Tags: php

While comparing the values in the below array

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string '09:30' (length=5)
      1 => string '11:00' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string '11:01' (length=5)
      1 => string '18:00' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '12:05' (length=5)
      1 => string '14:00' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string '14:00' (length=5)
      1 => string '20:20' (length=7)
```

If I am using `if($a > $b)`   it is even giving true for equal values  `($a = $b) // this is not comparision` ,
      while 
`if($a - $b > 0)` is giving accurate result.

**Why so ?**

**EDIT:** The code part where I am using cmp.

*This woks fine*

```
for($i=0; $i < $fr -1 ; $i++)
{
    if( $dtime[$i][1] - $dtime[$i+1][0] > 0 )
    {
        echo 'It is clashing';
        break;
    }
}
```

*This does not works fine*

```
for($i=0; $i < $fr -1 ; $i++)
{
    if( $dtime[$i][1] > $dtime[$i+1][0] )
    {
        echo 'It is clashing';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your comparison code? If you're literally typing `if ($a = $b)` you're doing the assignment operator, setting $a to the corntents of $b. You should be using `if ($a == $b)` or `if ($a === $b)` for comparison.  And when you say `$a - $b`, you're subtracting strings which doesn't really make sense. You should only subtract integers.

Comment: Do you want them to be compared as strings, numbers or times?

Comment: @TomFenech till yet the var_dumped array is shown to which I am implementing the condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the way you're doing comparisons seems odd, I think you have a data cleaning problem. In the top part of your question it appears you're doing a `var_dump()`. Notice how`'09:30' (length=5)` is correct but `'11:00' (length=7)` is wrong because the length should be 5 also. There are some additional hidden characters (maybe \n or \r) at the beginning or end of the data.

To fix, try running `$value = trim($value)` on each of your array elements before comparing.

Comment: Ok!!! ... Thanks .. That is where I was missing after taking $mval = trim(fgets($fp)); without trim function.